# inner_hits with nested syntax on PHP client for elasticsearch does not seem to work

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using the PHP client for elasticsearch (5.2.0) and fail to get the inner_hits results , this is my PHP query (which does not return the inner_hits)

```
    $params = [
    'index'  => 'caption_index',
    'type'   => 'caption',
    'body'   => [
        'query' => [
            'nested' => [
                'path' => 'lines',
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            ['match' => ['lines.content' => 'Totally different text' ]]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'inner_hits' => [ ]

            ]
        ]
    ],
    'client' => [ 'ignore' => 404 ] 
]; 
$results = $client->search($params);
```

Simultaneously I am running the same requests on Kibana  and I do get the answers correctly

```
    GET /caption_index/caption/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" :  "lines" ,
            "query": {
              "bool" : {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match" : 
                    { "lines.content" : "Totally different text" }
                  }
                ] 
              }
            },
            "inner_hits" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what is the difference and why the PHP won't show the results?

I can attach the current results but it seems like an overkill in this case - trust me - the inner hits is not there

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue with the ES PHP API, got it working by including a parameter in the `inner_hits` array.

For example:

```
'inner_hits' => ['name' => 'any-name']
```

You can find which parameters are allowed [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html).